# move from .netlify.app to domain.com in search console

Tags: redirect, dns, subdomain, netlify

I am trying to index my website with google search console, I already did it with my netlify subdomain, but now I changed my domain so I am using the Google Search Console Change Tool, but the problem I don’t know how to redirect from .netlify.app to .com and this is the error:

[image: Google search console error]

the solution is to redirect the selfimprovingbooks.netlify.app to selfimprovingbooks.com but I don't know if that is even possible, or at least that the selfimprovingbooks.netlify.app do not appear on google but selfimprovingbooks.com do, help please

[image: _redirects file code]

I tried to add this code to _redirects file but it doesn't work